# Merge columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-science

I would like to merge two dataframes with pandas by keeping the lines for which the title of the content on Netflix and its year are identical to the main title and the year of release of my second imdb datafram.

Do you know how I can do this?

I tried that, but unfortunately I don't sort my dataframes well according to the columns

As you can see, the columns in my two dataframes do not have the same names

```py
netflix.merge(imdb, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `left_on` and `right_on`.

Comment: Which image represents the netflix df? Which one is the imdb df?  It would be helpful if you submit the underlying data for both dataframes as text and include them in the code snipit you provided in your question.  To do that quickly, just execute the following and paste it into your question: netflix.to_dict().  If there are too many records, just submit a subset like so: netfilx.head(10).to_dict()

Comment: The one with the primarytitle is the daframe imdb, the others is the netflix dataframe boths are head(5)

Comment: I used left_on and right_on on my dataframe with the 'title' column, it works but now that I have a new dataframe how can I do the same for the release_year and startYear columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax looks to me incorrect , you did not pass two dataframe argument , refer the example below, it should help

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({
   'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
   'Name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'],
   'subject_id':['sub1','sub2','sub4','sub6','sub5']})
right = pd.DataFrame({
   'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
   'Name': ['Billy', 'Brian', 'Bran', 'Bryce', 'Betty'],
   'subject_id':['sub2','sub4','sub3','sub6','sub5']})
print(pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

Comment: thanks for the response, this one works but they didn't show me the two colums title side by side:   pd.merge(netflix, imdb, left_index=True, right_index=True)